# React native Flatlist grid and item header

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to custom a screen same:
[image]

so I use Flastlist and check if the item is header I will set with item = window.with and if not width item = window.width/3. But its error.
Here is my code:

```js
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window")
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            data: [
                { name: "Movies", header: true },
                { name: "Interstellar", header: false },
                { name: "Dark Knight", header: false },
                { name: "Pop", header: false },
                { name: "Music", header: true },
                { name: "Adams", header: false },
                { name: "Nirvana", header: false },
                { name: "Amrit Maan", header: false },
                { name: "Oye Hoye", header: false },
                { name: "Eminem", header: false },
                { name: "Places", header: true },
                { name: "Jordan", header: false },
                { name: "Punjab", header: false },
                { name: "Ludhiana", header: false },
                { name: "Jamshedpur", header: false },
                { name: "India", header: false },
                { name: "People", header: true },
                { name: "Jazzy", header: false },
                { name: "Appie", header: false },
                { name: "Baby", header: false },
                { name: "Sunil", header: false },
                { name: "Arrow", header: false },
                { name: "Things", header: true },
                { name: "table", header: false },
                { name: "chair", header: false },
                { name: "fan", header: false },
                { name: "cup", header: false },
                { name: "cube", header: false }
            ],
            stickyHeaderIndices: []
        };
    }
    renderItem(item) {
        if (item.header) {
            return (
                <View style={{ width: width, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={{
                    width: width / 3,
                    height: width / 3,
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'gray'
                }}>
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        this.renderItem(item)
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.name}

                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

and my result
[image]
I have the error: an item isn't header is a row, but I want to show 3 item in a row.

When added number column = 3 in flastlist with code :

```js
 <FlatList
  numColumns={3}
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (this.renderItem(item))}
  keyExtractor={item => item.name}
/>
```

I have result
[image]

How can I fix show 3 item in a row?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `numColumns = { 3 }` in Flatlist props. [Here](https://tutorialscapital.com/react-native-dynamically-toggle-grid-view-list-view-android-ios-tutorial/) you get detail solution to your problem.

Comment: I try add  numColumns  ={3} in my code but it not working.
I edit my question and add result

Answer (score 0):

I've used **nested FlatList** to solve this:

```
const renderCategory = category => (
    <View>
      <Text>{category}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={itemsByCategory[category]}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item)}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        numColumns={3}
      />
    </View>
  );

return (
    <FlatList
      data={Object.keys(itemsByCategory)}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => renderCategory(item)}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Normally we try to add a bit more text to posts to explain how the answer works. You can edit your answer to clarify it as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Using `flexWrap: 'wrap'` and `flexDirection: 'row'` in your main `container` should resolve your problem.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      this.renderItem(item)
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: add `flexDirection: 'row'` and check please.

Comment: I check add it in Flatlist and item render but it not working

Comment: Have you added this in main `container` `View`? Don't add in other `view`

Comment: if your code working please share it in https://snack.expo.io because I have tried the cases but not working

Comment: thank you  very much, I did it, with each item isn't header I render is a Flastlist :)

Comment: Sounds good. You may accept my answer if it helped you out :)

Comment: Could you post your solution to this issue?